# Using Microsoft graph API to retrieve a specific attribute

Tags: rest, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Hi (i'm new to this so you'll need to forgive me),

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph API to retrieve some user attributes from active directory.

I'm conducting some testing on [Microsoft graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) but i'm not entirely sure how to retrive a specific attribute called employeeID (which is needed). I've found out how to retrive some of the other basic information i need using the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "id": "6df92a63-2bef-477c-8c84-bf1113d5bd3e",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "SmithB",
    "givenName": "bob",
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": "example@example.com",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "smith",
    "userPrincipalName": "example@example.com"
}
```

However, i'm at a loss beyond this point. The docs seem to mention something about using `$select` but it seems to be more for refining a query rather than finding a specific attribute.

I'm sure there is a fairly simple solution and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction for how to query a specific attribute.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  What did it take to get it working?

Comment: The final solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45259741/7626823 Pay close attention to the use of `$select` in the get request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documented properties exposed on a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user), you will find there is no property called `EmployeeId`.

Now it could be that this property exists as an [Open Extension](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/opentypeextension) on the user object.

In that case you can [read here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/opentypeextension_get) on how to return the extension properties for the user object.

```
GET /users/{Id|userPrincipalName}/extensions/{extensionId}
```

Or you could be using [Schema Extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/schemaextension) for the same purpose.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/schemaExtensions
```

Either way, if you are certian that `EmployeeId` exists in your directory, you should know it is NOT a default property that is supported by Microsoft Graph or AAD. Instead it must be some extension that was added to your directory with one of the two extension methods above.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I guess this thread is pretty outdated. There is now a standard attribute in Azure AD exposed via Microsoft Graph API called "employeeId" as documented on [Official GraphAPI reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0)
It is not presented in the default response, but can be retrieved by `$select` argument like:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}?$select=givenName,surname,employeeId,etc...`